# using jQuery to control a drop down list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
    <select id="DropList">
          @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryList)
          {

            <option value="@item.Id">
                @item.Name
            </option>
          }
    </select>
```

This list holds categories of pictures. There is a database holds pictures information and categoy information. When i choose a category from the list, i want to see all the pictures that belong to the category. 
This is my list. I want the controller to give me pictures when i change the value in the list.
I am using jQuery to take the id from the selected list element but how can i get the pictures.

This code works:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryList)
        {
            <a id="aa" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = @item.Id })">@item.Name</a>

            <br />
        }
        <br />
        <a href="@Url.Content("http://localhost:55197/Home/CategoryEkle")">Yeni Kategori Ekle</a>
```

I want to the same for the drop down list.

Comment: Describe the problem you're seeing.  In what way does it not work?

Comment: Are you talking about how to do an ajax request with the value of the drop down?

Comment: I'd also suggest you create a ViewModel which contains a `SelectList` and pass this to your view. You can then replace your entire `foreach` statement with `@Html.DropDownList("DropList", mySelectList);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rory's comment on your post is a good one.  But rather than putting it in the ViewModel (since controllers don't care about the way that views display things), I'd do this in the view:

```
@{
    var cats = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in Model.CategoryList)
        cats.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item, Value = item.Id });
}

@Html.DropDownList("DropList", cats)
```